# Upload image binary objective c

Tags: swift, objective-c, binary, http-post, httprequest

I have one request where I want to upload image in binary as attached screenshot of postman.
Also the image request doesn't require key so sending a multipart / form data doesn't work here which I have already tried.

In android I am sending the same request as

```
httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(ImageData))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSvDJ.png)

Comment: Ask Postman to generate code (Swift or Objective-C) and see the logic. It's not beautiful code but you should see where and how to write it. I'd guess that's `request.httpBody = image.pngdata()`, or something like that.